# Micro services with JBOSS

Tags: jboss, microservices

I am new to Jboss, want to know if micro services architecture is a right choice on JBOSS. I cannot change the application server as it is decided by client architect and I have no choice.
Want to know whether we can develop micro services with underlying JBOSS application server.

I understand Spring boot comes with embedded tomcat container, which makes it flexible to stop and start, deploy individual service with no impact to other services.
However will that architecture works with JBoss too.

Please suggest.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

By the definition what micro services are, then conceptually yes. A micro service is a service that is an independent unit, it could deployed, updated, and undeployed independently without affecting any unrelated part of your application. So that would mean having multiple instances of JBoss for MS and your application calling them through some sort of gateway or any other mechanism depending on your use case. If you plan to deploy all your MS in the same JBoss instance then it defeats the very purpose of a MS. Given that, JBoss wouldn't be a right choice for MS deployment because it will only make your MS deployment infrastructure quite heavy.

Depending on what your client's requirements are, your could possibly keep your webapp in JBoss and deploy your MS containers separately.

Comment: Thanks for a nice explanation. What do you mean by "you could possibly keep your webapp in JBoss and deploy your MS containers separately."

Comment: The fact that you are considering MS, I believe you have identified the scope of functionality they would offer. So what I mean is that these individual services could be implemented as self contained MS with Spring Boot or Dropwizard like libraries while your front end server still remains JBoss. You should also evaluate whether MS is really a right fit for you in first place.

Comment: Thanks. Today i did some research on micro services using spring boot. However i couldn't find any successful case anywhere deploying a spring boot application into jboss. Can you guide me with any useful links/references please.

Comment: So again, you could do it conceptually but not a recommended way of doing it for microservices. Here is how it can be done https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/

Comment: FWIW our product runs the front-end in Jboss and have several services that use Spring outside of Jboss. However we deploy the whole thing on a VM which is distributed to customers. We are trying to extract more services away from Jboss. So it can be done, but given the choice I'm not sure we'd pick this hybrid again.

Answer (score 4):

I actually developed a feasibility study to investigate the solution you mentioned. My conclusion is that it is totally viable to use Micro Service principles in a JBoss Platform.

I used the combination of JBoss \ Spring Boot \ Netflix to create successful Micro Service stack, I personally do that to find a solution to the transaction problem (multiple micro services collaborating) and the fan out problem which caused because excessive Network communication and Serialization costs.

I also wrote a blog about the subject, you might find more details there if you like to, here is the link.

[Micro Services – Fan Out, Transaction Problems and Solutions with Spring Boot/JBoss and Netflix Eureka](https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2016/11/05/micro-services-fan-out-transaction-problems-and-solutions-with-spring-bootjboss-and-netflix-eureka/)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to get out of microservices.

Some of the developers at my organisation looked at Spring Boot but concluded that it's best off being run as a standalone container rather than in JBoss, otherwise you've effectively got two container frameworks competing (SB and JBoss) and a range of associated issues.

Deploying microservices in JBoss won't give you the same flexibility as a true container system like Docker. With Docker you create standalone packages for your microservices that contain all the code, system tools, runtime environment, etc. It can be as small or large as it needs to be. JBoss on the other hand is a large container running a single JVM designed to hold multiple applications. The level of isolation is not the same, and it's not efficient to have JBoss as a container for a single microservice so you have to appropriately size and then deploy to the instance to make use of the resources it has available.

If you're looking at microservices as a way to gain greater control over service lifecycle management (deployment, versioning, deprecating, etc.) as opposed to an automated, web-scale component deployment model a la Netflix or LinkedIn, you could do this adequately with JBoss.

I'm actually looking to do something along these lines here. It won't be true microservices but by packaging and deploying individual, properly versioned APIs rather than monolithic applications and following most of the other principles of microservice development (componentisation, business function focus, stateless etc.) we will be hopefully better able to manage and benefit from our APIs.

Our APIs will all be behind an API gateway and load balancer so we can choose how we distribute the microserves distributed across the JBoss instances and balance resource usage as required. Note that our organisation is relatively small and has relatively low and predictable traffic so this approach should work fine. Your needs however may be different.